# Vuejs2 - computed property in components

Tags: computed-properties, vuejs2

I have a component to display names. I need to calculate number of letters for each name.
I added `nameLength` as computed property but vuejs doesn't determine this property in loop.

```
var listing = Vue.extend({
    template: '#users-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            query: '',
            list: [],
            user: '',
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedList: function () {
            var vm = this;
            return this.list.filter(function (item) {
                return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(vm.query.toLowerCase()) !== -1
            })
        },
        nameLength: function () {
            return this.length; //calculate length of current item
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.loadItems();
    },
    methods: {
        loadItems: function () {
            this.list = ['mike','arnold','tony']
        },
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apokjqxx/22/

So result expected

mike-4

arnold-6

tony-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems there is some misunderstanding about computed property.
I have created fork from you fiddle, it will work as you needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/6vhjq11v/5/

```
nameLength: function () {
    return this.length; //calculate length of current item
}
```

in comment it shows that "calculate length of current item"
but js cant get the concept of current item

```
this.length
```

this will execute length on Vue component it self not on that value.

computed property work on other property of instance and return value.

but here you are not specifying anything to it and used this so it wont able to use any property.

if you need any more info please comment.

Comment: Thanks Hardik, but your jsfiddle example isn't working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6vhjq11v/5/ try this one sorry for that forgot to update that

Comment: Thanks, if move calculate length to method that works fine as expected. Just interesting if is exists a way to use computed. Example https://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property to compute FullName....

Comment: you are right but you can see that is using model values , and in our case we are using this.. you can compute but you need specific modal/variable for that

Comment: Thanks for clarify. Next step is find way to make method reusable for other components :)